# Amazon S3 - Access Denied when remove all url parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Why I got access denied when remove all url parameters to preview video file compare to image? I can view image file rather than video preview.

Error
https://s3.amazonaws.com/izify/bisnes.avi

With specific URL parameters.
[https://s3.amazonaws.com/izify/bisnes.avi?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAIOIWIXXLUZFLTJ7A&Expires=1389971001&Signature=ZBMtwWOeKMYDiYStueoScpRKrjY%3D&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEI///////////wEawAIOAmaJaqs0dLEqhoLqN4xDEr4Pv83018/ywiBPuFdLYvjKW0T/rqnYl9WPIUtSPYVPNWTful6Enbh1TeYY8JC1EFFeekkHITLk/m83FSn55FKsT6vDsQSmfq4tA/kcgU6AW77PznYgLolatEs3wfQ6y8hWI2ga2P%2BRjJhsuNvYVb6tu/qiHv8fGwtMC%2Bk2X5tw01M8wZtrmr57137FcqMjZ1p86irjoBUSisW5D9ay%2BIhf1DdfNV4q2qYOy7RT4jMOKxl%2B%2BJmYaFxjVLjecRUckpKf2TTwY5WZ9Yvz/vl8DTvAx7lExTacODkyjCJ1mSyhWsvh3O2OUnavPa1tOhblQ68AsGyhDGzeeT2YqleuTGdNGUPJfXSlPusAnNlkb8W6yQfPF0JRcEse7MMkBmS2OzCgLTd3SJw5F0rqqhC0jSCh9%2BSWBQ%3D%3D](https://s3.amazonaws.com/izify/bisnes.avi?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAIOIWIXXLUZFLTJ7A&Expires=1389971001&Signature=ZBMtwWOeKMYDiYStueoScpRKrjY=&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEI///////////wEawAIOAmaJaqs0dLEqhoLqN4xDEr4Pv83018/ywiBPuFdLYvjKW0T/rqnYl9WPIUtSPYVPNWTful6Enbh1TeYY8JC1EFFeekkHITLk/m83FSn55FKsT6vDsQSmfq4tA/kcgU6AW77PznYgLolatEs3wfQ6y8hWI2ga2P%2bRjJhsuNvYVb6tu/qiHv8fGwtMC%2bk2X5tw01M8wZtrmr57137FcqMjZ1p86irjoBUSisW5D9ay%2bIhf1DdfNV4q2qYOy7RT4jMOKxl%2b%2bJmYaFxjVLjecRUckpKf2TTwY5WZ9Yvz/vl8DTvAx7lExTacODkyjCJ1mSyhWsvh3O2OUnavPa1tOhblQ68AsGyhDGzeeT2YqleuTGdNGUPJfXSlPusAnNlkb8W6yQfPF0JRcEse7MMkBmS2OzCgLTd3SJw5F0rqqhC0jSCh9%2bSWBQ==)

Image with and without url parameters
https://s3.amazonaws.com/izify/w3_1389194950.png

[https://s3.amazonaws.com/izify/w3_1389194950.png?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAIOIWIXXLUZFLTJ7A&Expires=1389971357&Signature=kPinx9ZekVaAzfHQDuoqBMPHGvE%3D&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEI///////////wEawAIOAmaJaqs0dLEqhoLqN4xDEr4Pv83018/ywiBPuFdLYvjKW0T/rqnYl9WPIUtSPYVPNWTful6Enbh1TeYY8JC1EFFeekkHITLk/m83FSn55FKsT6vDsQSmfq4tA/kcgU6AW77PznYgLolatEs3wfQ6y8hWI2ga2P%2BRjJhsuNvYVb6tu/qiHv8fGwtMC%2Bk2X5tw01M8wZtrmr57137FcqMjZ1p86irjoBUSisW5D9ay%2BIhf1DdfNV4q2qYOy7RT4jMOKxl%2B%2BJmYaFxjVLjecRUckpKf2TTwY5WZ9Yvz/vl8DTvAx7lExTacODkyjCJ1mSyhWsvh3O2OUnavPa1tOhblQ68AsGyhDGzeeT2YqleuTGdNGUPJfXSlPusAnNlkb8W6yQfPF0JRcEse7MMkBmS2OzCgLTd3SJw5F0rqqhC0jSCh9%2BSWBQ%3D%3D](https://s3.amazonaws.com/izify/w3_1389194950.png?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAIOIWIXXLUZFLTJ7A&Expires=1389971357&Signature=kPinx9ZekVaAzfHQDuoqBMPHGvE=&x-amz-security-token=AQoDYXdzEI///////////wEawAIOAmaJaqs0dLEqhoLqN4xDEr4Pv83018/ywiBPuFdLYvjKW0T/rqnYl9WPIUtSPYVPNWTful6Enbh1TeYY8JC1EFFeekkHITLk/m83FSn55FKsT6vDsQSmfq4tA/kcgU6AW77PznYgLolatEs3wfQ6y8hWI2ga2P%2bRjJhsuNvYVb6tu/qiHv8fGwtMC%2bk2X5tw01M8wZtrmr57137FcqMjZ1p86irjoBUSisW5D9ay%2bIhf1DdfNV4q2qYOy7RT4jMOKxl%2b%2bJmYaFxjVLjecRUckpKf2TTwY5WZ9Yvz/vl8DTvAx7lExTacODkyjCJ1mSyhWsvh3O2OUnavPa1tOhblQ68AsGyhDGzeeT2YqleuTGdNGUPJfXSlPusAnNlkb8W6yQfPF0JRcEse7MMkBmS2OzCgLTd3SJw5F0rqqhC0jSCh9%2bSWBQ==)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your permissions for the file (object) make sure they are readable by everyone. You can check in the AWS S3 Console. See the example below:

[image]

Comment: How to do that for multiple files?

Comment: @HungryMind you can use something like the aws cli or the s3cmd tool. https://aws.amazon.com/cli/, http://s3tools.org/s3cmd